# JDBC Query returns null

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I'm creating a database using JDBC which contains the tables `Konten`and `HAUPTKONTO_1`. Both have an integer column named `id`

These are my SQL statement to create and populate the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "Konten"("id" "integer","typ" "string", "name" "string","ausgleichsDatum" "integer","wechselDatum" "integer", "beschreibung" "string" );

CREATE TABLE "HAUPTKONTO_1"("id" "integer","typ" "string","datum" "datetime","beschreibung" "string","wert" "numeric","summe" "integer" )

INSERT INTO Konten VALUES ('1', 'HAUPTKONTO', 'Mein Bankkontolein','0','0','bei der 0815 bank für mein Geld')

INSERT INTO Konten VALUES ('2', 'KONTO', 'Mein Bankkontolein','0','0','bei der 0815 bank für mein Geld')

INSERT INTO HAUPTKONTO_1 values( '1 ' , ' BUCHUNG ' , ' 01.01.2001 ' , ' meine erste Transaktion ' , ' 1 ' , ' 1 ' ) 

INSERT INTO HAUPTKONTO_1 values( '2 ' , ' BUCHUNG ' , ' 01.01.2002 ' , ' meine zweite Transaktion ' , ' 3 ' , ' 4 ' )
```

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
select * from HAUPTKONTO_1 WHERE id ='1'
```

or

```
select * from HAUPTKONTO_1 WHERE typ ='BUCHUNG'
```

or

```
select * from HAUPTKONTO_1 WHERE typ  like 'BUCHUNG'
```

using

```
dv.getStatement().executeQuery(befehl);
```

But I don't get any results.

```
select * from HAUPTKONTO_1

select * from Konten WHERE id ='1'
```

those two queries work without problems.

The [SQLite Databrowser](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/sqlite_database_browser_portable) shows the same problem:

It works with the SQLite Manager in Firefox.

Comment: This is an english speaking site. And btw: `'1'` is a string literal, `1` is a number in SQL. Do not compare apples to oranges. `where id = '1'` compares a number to a string. Even though it might seem to work it is not good coding style (other DBMS might be much more restrictive)

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces around all values; `'1'` is not the same as `'1 '`:

```
INSERT INTO HAUPTKONTO_1 values( '1 ' , ' BUCHUNG ' , ' 01.01.2001 ' , ' meine erste Transaktion ' , ' 1 ' , ' 1 ' )
```